# How to hint maven to build one module before another if it is not a jar dependency

Tags: java, maven, dependencies, frontend

I have a maven module (let's call it frontend) which contains no java code but instead uses `frontend-maven-plugin` to build a js frontend. Another (backend) module uses the built data from the frontend module and embeds it in itself via the `maven-assembly-plugin` like this.

```
    <fileSet>
        <directory>${project.parent.basedir}/frontend/target/dist</directory>
        <outputDirectory>/</outputDirectory>
    </fileSet>
```

This works, however when running maven install on the project containing these two modules, backend module seems to always build first, which means it either doesn't pick up the front-end files (in case of a first time build or `clean install`) or it always picks up the previous build. I've read that maven decides the build order by checking if the modules depend on each other either as dependencies or plugins or something, however as the frontend module is not java, it can't work as a dependency. Is there any other way I can hint to maven to consider building frontend first?

Comment: define correct dependencies between those modules which defines the correct build order...

Comment: But how can I do that if the frontend module is not a jar?

Comment: Move `frontend` module before `backend` module in main pom.xml. If the modules do not depend on each other, maven builds in the order in which the modules are declared in main pom.xml

Comment: If you are packaging the frontend module via maven-assembly you have to use a dependency on the frontend module which defines the order of built. A strongly recommend not to rely on the module order in parent pom...always define it explicitly.

Answer (score 0):

You need to explicitly mention the **type** of the dependency

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>xxx</groupId>
    <artifactId>yyyy</artifactId>
    <type>pom</type>
</dependency>
```